# String match between two data frame columns

Tags: r, string

I want to do a string match for 'product' column in data set A with 'Description' column in dataset B and get the corresponding cost. If no match found I want something like 'NA' or 'No match'

The two data set look like this:

data set A:

```
Country     Product
AUS     BANLORE 5MG B/90 CP
BNG     BANLORE 5MG TAB VNAM X 30
SL      BANLORE CAPS 10MGX30 M/T
RIO     BANLORE CAPS 10MGX30 M/T
AP      CADBURY 10/20MG FT 30PCS WI
BP      CADBURY 5/10MG X 10 TABS.
GUJ     CADBURY 5/20MG X 10 TABS.
KEL     CADBURY 5/10MG FT 30PS ML
PON     CHOCO 10MG FT 30 RO
TN      CHOCO 20MG FT 30  
HYD     CHOCO 40MG FT 14
CHN     LACTO 2G 20ML LIQ
NAG     LACTO 1G 10ML LIQ
NEP     LACTO INJ 1000MG 
ASM     LACTO INJ 2000MG/20ML 10S
```

and the second data set is:

data set B:

```
Description                     Group       Cost
BANLORE CAPS 10MG X 30'S        Novas       6.34
BANLORE 5MG TAB VNAM X 30       Novas       4.05
BANLORE CAPS 5MG X 10'S         Novas       5.29
CADBURY TAB 10MG/10MG X 7'S     Cadet       7.77
CADBURY 10MG/10MG X30'S         Cadet       4.03
CADBURY 5/20MG FT 7PS           Cadet       1.98
CADBURY 5/20MG X 10 TABS        Cadet       0.28
CHOCO  20MG FCT BLST            PEPSCO      0.18
CHOCO 10MG FT 30                PEPSCO      2.62
LACTO INJ 100MG/5ML 5S          star        5.17
LACTO INJ 500MG/25ML 1'S        star        8.79
LACTO INJ 2000MG/20ML 10S       star        6.44
```

I output looks like the one below:

```
Country     Product                     cost

AUS     BANLORE 5MG B/90 CP             NO MATCH
BNG     BANLORE 5MG TAB VNAM X 30       4.05
RIO     BANLORE CAPS 10MGX30 M/T        NO MATCH
AP      CADBURY 5/20MG X 10 TABS        0.28
GUJ     LACTO INJ 2000MG/20ML 10S       6.44
KEL     CADBURY 5/10MG FT 30PS ML       NO MATCH
```

I tried using grep and Levenshtein distance but could not arrive at a proper solution.

Comment: In your dataset `B`, the description for the cost 6.34 is `BANLORE CAPS 10MG X 30'S`.  So, why you have 6.34 with ` BANLORE 5MG B/90 CP` in your expected output ?

Comment: I noticed that you edited.  IN that case, the 2nd row for cost would  be `NO MATCH` as it is 5MG and in datasetB, that is 10MG?

Comment: I have just given random numbers in the output.

Comment: I don't know what your expected output is and if you don't provide any accurate description, it would only serve to confuse others especially when you have partial matches.

Comment: Akrun thanks for the reply,  

I would want to do a match between Product and descriptions columns of the data set and return the relevant cost details after the match.

Comment: look at [merge](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/merge.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for presize matches,

```
A$cost <- B$Cost[match(A$Product, B$Description)]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrei,I tried your approach but did get the desired output.